# Doctrine UnitOfWork extra queries for atomic field change

Tags: doctrine-orm

I find myself in the situation where I want to execute a raw SQL (or a DQL) in the same transaction when `flush` is called, like so:

```
$em->persist($obj);
// add `UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = X`
$em->flush()
```

I looked around and I couldn't find any place where I could inject my SQL like that.

This would happen in a function that doesn't know or care when `flush` is called, and doesn't want to call `flush` itself or do this:

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
$em->flush($obj);
$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate('UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = X');
$em->getConnection()->commit();
```

Is there a built-in way of doing this, before I go and make my own event handler and service that gather SQL from all over the place and execute it on flush?

Comment: **The** way to to something like this is using Doctrine Events and creating your own event listener. Is that what you mean by _"make my own event handler"_?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. If there's nothing built-in then I'd have a service which collects SQL statements and a Doctrine event handler that handles `onFlush` and executes those SQL statements at that point.

Comment: Then that's the way to go for you.